# How can functions be called as an argument for a function?

Tags: javascript

The code that brought this question to my mind (and that I am trying to understand) is:

```
function sum(numbers) {
    var total = 0;
    forEach(numbers, function (number) {
        total += number;
    });
    return total;
}
show(sum([1, 10, 100]));
```

p.s forEach is a function that does this:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]);
}
```

I would like an explanation of how the code above works, as I don't understand how a function can be called as an argument for a function.

Comment: Have you looked online for information about anonymous functions in javascript at all? I guarantee that you'll be able to find a VERY detailed explanation of this elsewhere

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html

Comment: Functions are objects. You can pass them around like you'd pass any other data. The functions always keep their original variable scope, which is why it can still use the `total` variable after you've passed it.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm mostly concerned about how a function can be called as an argument for a function.

It's not called in the argument - the function itself is passed. In JavaScript, functions are [first-class values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen); they are objects which *can* be invoked with parenthesis, but they also have normal properties (like `.prototype` or `.name`) and inherited methods (like `.call`, `.bind`). Have a look at the [docs for `Function` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Your `sum` code is creating an anonymous function, and passes the reference to it into the `forEach` function where it is stored in the `action` variable. It then is getting invoked from there.

The concept of passing functions around to be invoked with values determined by another method is named [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: I looked deeper into the functions and figured out what it does, your answers gave me more insight. Thanks!!!